# Why do i need two _getch() to get the correct value?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, arrow-keys

I was trying to find the character code for arrow keys so wrote this-

```
char x=_getch();
cout<<(int)x;
```

No matter which arrow key I pressed it printed -32. Then I added one line and my code looked like this-

```
char x=_getch();
x=_getch();
cout<<(int)x;
```

With the above code it was printing correct values. Can anyone explain why this is happening.
I am using Code::Blocks with GNU GCC Compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will answer your question
[image]

A similar question has been answered at the following link.

[getch and arrow codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463201/getch-and-arrow-codes)

This is the screenshot from one of the answer's from that link