# C++: User input gives unwanted behaviour

Tags: c++, iostream

When I use the normal `std::cin` or `std::cin.get()` or `std::getline()` functions, I get unwanted (but understandable) behaviour.

When you use the arrow keys to move back for example, you don't move back, but you input something like "^[[D" into the console.

Is there a way to make the std input function more like, let's say the Python terminal environment?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463201/getch-and-arrow-codes

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot do it with the standard library. The only approximation is outputting the backspace character `\b` and hope it does the right thing in the user's environment.

You will need to use either system APIs or libraries like `readline` or `ncurses`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was afraid of that... I'm going to try ncurses.

Comment: @wouter_ensink You're welcome! :) If you found an answer useful, please mark it as accepted!