# Emulate keyboard event arrow keys in C

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi, keyboard, ipod

Short: help emulate keyboard events (arrow keys, enter) in C code under linux.

Long: I am working at interfacing iPod clickwheel with Raspberry Pi. At the moment i can printf to terminal something like "button 1 pressed". But i need system-wide event, just like a keypress from real keyboard. My other code is on C so i cant implement Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe use SDL2, it works with Raspberry Pi and Linux and you can manage inputs events such as keyboard, mouse, pads etc.

More info here: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Event

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks but i cant find simple enough example of this pretty new to me library. I would be happy to find something like this proto code: keyboardEvent(KEY_UP,1);

Comment: Simple example of how you could write a piece of code that manage the key input:
`
SDL_Event event;
bool continuer = true
while (continuer) {
        SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
        switch (event.type) {
            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                switch (event.key.keysym.sym) {
                    case SDLK_1:
                        continuer=false;
                        `break;`
                `}` 
Code loops forever until the 1 key is pressed. Find more info if you search for "How to manage SDL events and inputs

Answer (score 0):

You really should use third-party libraries. There's definitely no platform-independent way to do it in ANSI C. You can try using `conio.h` with its kbhit() function , the library can be downloaded from [conio](https://github.com/zoelabbb/conio.h/blob/master/conio.h).

Or you can read the up /down /right /left keys from the terminal
[like](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11432632/17061999)