# Weird behavior of getchar()

Tags: c, while-loop, getchar

Currently, I am doing a project in c language in which I have to write a while loop to constant receive either keyboard input or joystick input. The joystick input is okay but for the keyboard input, there are 2 types of inputs: arrow and normal input ('a', 'b', ...). For the keyboard input, I referred to this link (https://stackoverflow.com/a/11432632) to receive arrow keys.
Here is my code:

```
while(true){
    if (getchar() == '\033') { // if the first value is esc
        getchar(); // skip the [
        switch(getchar()) { // the real value
        case 'A':
            printf("arrow up \n");
            break;
        case 'B':
            printf("arrow down \n");
            break;
        case 'C':
            printf("arrow right \n");
            break;
        case 'D':
            printf("arrow left \n");
            break;
        }
    }
    if (getchar() != '\033'){
        printf("non arrow \n");
    }
}
```

However, the "non arrow" constantly appears even though I pressed arrow button.

If I changed the code from printf("non arrow \n") by have a variable char c, assign getchar() to it and later print c:

```
    if (getchar() != '\033'){
                printf("non arrow \n");
            }
```

The output will be as expected for arrow key (receive and print as expected) but nothing appeared when 'e' or 'r' or other single character key is entered.

I wonder what is the problem for my code and how can I modify it to receive behavior as I want.

I hope to receive answer soon.

Thank you, Huy Nguyen.

Comment: `getchar(); // skip the [` is not robust.  Rather than assume the return value is `'['`, test it.  If not, take evasive action.

Answer (score 1):

You're reading another character when you do `if (getchar() != '\033')`, not testing the same character that you tested the first time.

Use `else` instead of calling `getchar()` again.

```
while(true){
    if (getchar() == '\e') { // if the first value is esc
        getchar(); // skip the [
        switch(getchar()) { // the real value
        case 'A':
            printf("arrow up \n");
            break;
        case 'B':
            printf("arrow down \n");
            break;
        case 'C':
            printf("arrow right \n");
            break;
        case 'D':
            printf("arrow left \n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("non arrow\n");
        }
    } else {
        printf("non arrow \n");
    }
}
```

I've added a `default:` case to the `switch` in case they send a different escape sequence. You should probably also check that the first character after `ESC` is `[`, not just assume it will be.

If you have more than two conditions, you can use `switch(getchar())` there, like you do with the character after `ESC [`, or you can assign the result of `getchar()` to a variable and test that in the conditions.

Also, you should use `else if` when you're testing mutually-exclusive conditions.

Comment: Ah I think I got it after using switch case. Thank you