# JavaScript - How to enable arrow key in Firefox browser while validating input fields against special characters

Tags: javascript

I'm validating my input field using key code  to enter (a-z, A-Z, _). The javascript code looks something like this:

```
function checkForSpecialCharacters(event) {
var keycode;

keycode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which;

if ((keycode >= 48 && keycode <= 57) || (keycode >= 65 && keycode <= 90) || (keycode == 9)
        || (keycode == 95)||(keycode == 8) || (keycode >= 97 && keycode <= 122)) {

    return true;

}

else {

    return false;

}
return true;
```

}

This works pretty fine in Chrome, IEs, but in firefox it prevents arrow key also.

I've gone through [What are the ascii values of up down left right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876275/what-are-the-ascii-values-of-up-down-left-right). But In  my case I need to prevent to enter all the special characters in input field.
The give solution in the above link does not fulfill my requirement.

Kindly reply with your positive response.

Thanks.

Comment: You should consider testing your code on Mac OS too. I had a little surprise when I've tested simillar code to your's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the solution of this problem. Just use `event.which`. Here ***which*** is a property of the event object. It contains the key code of the key which was pressed to trigger the event (eg: keydown, keyup etc.).

So just get the value fo the key pressed using `event.which` and check in if condition.

In my case in Firefox browser I was getting 0 for arrow keys. so I just added on more **or condition** like:

```
if ((keycode >= 48 && keycode <= 57) || (keycode >= 65 && keycode <= 90) || (keycode == 9)
 || (event.which == 0)  || (keycode == 95)||(keycode == 8) || (keycode >= 97 && keycode <= 122)) {

return true;}
```

Hope it will help other pal.

Thanks

Comment: You could have tested the keys in firebug or in other browsers using their webdeveloper tools.