# Why the output is different in both cases?

Tags: c, input, output

This is the first code

```
int main()
{
   int ch;
   while(ch)
   {
       ch=getch();
       printf("%d",ch);
       printf("\n");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

if in the above code I input

```
up arrow key 
down arrow key 
right arrow key 
left arrow key
```

RESPECTIVELY the the outputs are as following

```
224
72

224
80

224
77

224
75
```

but if I remove the LOOP from the code ie

```
int main()
{
   int ch;
   ch=getch();
   printf("%d",ch);
   printf("\n");
   return 0;
}
```

and input

```
up arrow key
down arrow key
right arrow key
left arrow key
```

RESPECTIVELY then the outputs are as follows

```
224
224
224
224
```

From where

```
224
```

is coming in the first code 
and after removing the LOOP
where the following numbers are gone

```
72
80
77
75
```

Comment: You should learn how to indent C code correctly.

Answer (score 3):

`getch()` fetches the next character from the console, but some keys like `up arrow key` etc. produce two successive "characters". Thus, when you remove the loop, you always only read the first character, but not the second one.

Generally, reading and handling special keys such as the cursor keys is very system specific and not defined in the C language - you would usually use an additional library (e.g. ncurses on Unix) to handle these.

As a last resort, you could also check if the first call to `getch()` returns the value `224` and in that case call it again, something like this:

```
int key = getch();
if (key == 224) {
    key = 0x100 + getch();   // arrow keys will have values > 256
}

...

switch(key) {
   case 0x142 : printf("Key up"); break;
   ...
}
```

But note that this is completely unportable and very system dependent. You should at least encapsulate it in a separate function and define some constants for the various keys.

See also

- [getch and arrow codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463201/getch-and-arrow-codes)
- [What are the ascii values of up down left right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876275/what-are-the-ascii-values-of-up-down-left-right)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio

Comment: if inputs like    arrow keys     produce two successive characters then how to input them from the keyboard.
    
    I mean to say 

    up arrow key==224 
or
up arrow key==72

Comment: you have to read the first key , then if it was 224 you can say that it's a functional key , then you have to read the second to decide which function it denote

Answer (score 0):

224 denoted that it's a functional key , so you have to get the next byte then you'll decide if the next byte was 72 then its Up arrow and so on

here is an example

```
int a,b;
while(a=getch())
{
    if(a==224)
    {
        b=getch();
        switch(b)
        {
             case 72:puts("Up arrow");break;
             case 80:puts("Down arrow");break;
             case 75:puts("Left arrow");break;
             case 77:puts("Right arrow");break;
         }
     }
 }
```

your second code will output 224 and stop , because no loop in there , try this :

```
a=getch(),b=getch();
printf("%d %d\n",a,b);
```

Comment: you code works even when you ... switch(a) and remove the "if" condition and remove the b=getch();

Comment: No , this is not going to work because 72 is the ASCII value for 'H' and 80 for 'P' and so on , you have to handle the 224 to ensure that the following is the Arrow ID

Comment: now try typing  'H' or 'P'  or 'K' or 'M' and you will see what I'm talking about ;)

Comment: you are also right my friend...

H and UP ARROW KEY both are printing UP ARROW

Comment: and that's why you have to write the `if` statement for the value `224` then write the `switch` :)

Comment: but why without the "if" statement the code if working for the arrow keys...ie why it is ignoring 224 and taking only 72 and hence works for both UP KEY and H......why?

Comment: Because it will Discard the first byte `224` and handle the arrow Id just like any other key pressed [i.e. it can't decide whether it's an arrow or an Alphabetical character] and that's why they make the first byte unique`224` so you can ensure that the next byte is not a normal ASCII char

Comment: but it is discarding the 224 in case of while loop only  ...ie....
if I remove while loop in your program ie  ch=getch()...if(ch==72)...printf("up key"); then it is not printing up key...ie it has not discarded the 224....but in case of loop why it discard it..

Comment: please tell me how you highlight a letter in comment box...then I will type both the modified codes of yours

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45197/discussion-between-user3180902-and-mostafa-36a2)

Comment: just use the same key of ~ [wothout pressing shift] ,any way without a loop , the `224` will not match the values in the `if`s [72,77,75,80] and so it will not print any thing, in a loop this [unmatch cycle ] will pass and the the arrow Id will match one of the values [72,77,75,80] in the second cycle. when I said discard I ment pass the cycle without doing any thing .