# "ASCII" codes for arrow up, down, left and right

Tags: java, jquery, bash, ascii

I am writing a program that reads input from Javascript and send those readings to bash.

I can successfully run many actions, like "A-Z" letters, TAB, CTRL+C, etc. But I realize that I cannot send properly to bash the ARROW UP.

If I read the ascii code from Javascript, I get the following as explained [Binding arrow keys in JS/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402698/binding-arrow-keys-in-js-jquery)

```
37 - left
38 - up
39 - right
40 - down
```

However, when I send arrow up to the terminal, decimal key code 38, I write an ampersand (as by following a ascii table http://www.asciitable.com/)

So, my question is: what code do I have to send from Java to bash to tell bash "arrow key up" ?

PD_ I realize that it might be different depending on the operating system and this code might not be considered an ascii code as this post suggest: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876275/what-are-the-ascii-values-of-up-down-left-right)

**Edit**
I write from Java to bash by using the following code:

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
[...]
Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");
OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();
out.write(asciiDecimalCode); // send characters
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mention Java, Javascript and bash here. Whatever are you doing?

Comment: Why are you trying to send up arrow to bash?  A java program is not a user.

Comment: Reading the characters from JavaScript and sending it to bash using Java. In the context makes sense.

Comment: Those codes you have are not ASCII codes, they are just key mapping codes of the keyboard, and may vary depending on manufacturer and localization.

Comment: That means that it cannot be done ?

Comment: he seems to be trying to make a web terminal , it can be used to get all info about your server , if in case you are redirecting bash output to your page as well , and about the Question , can you show the code where your ASCII values get posted in bash.

Comment: Correct, I am creating a web terminal. This program is due curiosity more than anything. It is an Javascript Terminal. (I do not understand the negative point). I edited the main question and added the code that I used to write to bash. It is just writing decimal values thought a OutputStream by using the ChannelShell of JSch.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The escape sequence for "Arrow up" is `"\u001b[A"`. `\u001b` is the code for [ESC (Escape)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#ASCII_escape_character).

That means while you have a single key code in JavaScript, you need to write 3 bytes to BASH to achieve the desired effect.

You can see it for yourself by typing <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd>.

The <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> tells bash: "Don't try to interpret the next input; just insert it verbatim".

Related:

- [Escape sequences for cursor movement](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html)

Comment: Huh, I'm getting `error: illegal escape character` when I try that in Java.

Comment: Of course. Java only supports Unicode escape sequences. Fixed.

Comment: If there is someone from Swift, the String is "\u{1b}[A"