# Arduino Sending Serial Command for Keyboard to Press Up ARrow

Tags: keyboard, arduino, ascii

I want to use Arduino and write keyboard commands for the up/down/left/right arrow. I was wondering how I would be able to do this with

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/KeyboardWrite

?

Comment: Check this post to  know what you have to send to emulate arrow keys: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876275/what-are-the-ascii-values-of-up-down-left-right

Answer (score 1):

You can use like:
`Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_ARROW);
Keyboard.press(KEY_RIGHT_ARROW);`
etc...