# opencv handling arrow keys with waitKey() function

Tags: opencv, keyboard

I want to handling arrow keys. but when I print out the input value for waitKey() function, It's 0.
I don't know why.
I try to change from "int" to "char" , but It doesn't work.
How can I solve this problem.

```
int pos = 100;
imshow("image", image);
onChange(pos, (void *)&image);
createTrackbar("threshold", "image", &pos, 255, onChange, (void*)&image);
while (1) {
    int Key = waitKey();
    cout << Key << endl;
    if (Key == 27) break;
    if (Key == 2490368) {
        pos--;
        onChange(pos, (void *)&image);
    }
    if(Key == 2621440){
        pos++;
        onChange(pos, (void *)&image);
    }
    if (pos < 0 || pos > 255) pos = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use `waitKeyEx()` function instead. As the documentation says:

> Similar to waitKey(), but returns full key code.
>
> Key code is implementation specific and depends on used backend:
>   QT/GTK/Win32

On my system it gives:
Left: 2424832
Up: 2490368
Right: 2555904
Down: 2621440

Although there are many online sources saying `waitKey()` works with arrows, it didn't return proper key codes on my Windows system either (always returned 0). Guess that is also implementation specific. Maybe because `waitKey()` returns ASCII-codes, but arrow keys don't have them (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876275/what-are-the-ascii-values-of-up-down-left-right)).

Comment: I just noted because of you reference to the _used backend_ for example in Win32 with can just do **0x10000 * 0x25 = 2424832** _(Left Arrow)_ and that way we could also use the virtual key codes from msdn https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/virtual-key-codes

Answer (score 4):

Note that this depends on version, on windows with 3.0 waitKey() gave full key codes, but when I changed to 3.3, it suddenly returned 0 for arrow keys.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my temporary workaround

```
#ifndef _WIN32
int myWaitKey(int wait) {
    int c = cv::waitKey(wait);
    return c;
}
#pragma message("linux..")
#else
#include <conio.h> // to support _getch
int myWaitKey(int wait) {
    int c = cvWaitKey(wait);
    if (c == 0) {
        int c = _getch();   //capture the key code and insert into c
        if (c == 0 || c == 224)
            c = _getch();
    }
    //if (c!=-1) printf("%d\n",c);
    return c;
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

with waitkey() in your code,keep the left click pressed on the cv2.trackbar icon and use the arrow keys to move in increments of 1