# What is \xe0 in the msvcrt.getch() method?

Tags: python, character-encoding

In the msvcrt.getch() method, when I enter any value that isn't in the ascii table, I get '\xe0' all the time. I don't know what this means

```
>>>import msvcrt
>>>up_arrow = msvcrt.getch()
>>> # this is where I have inputed the up arrow
>>>print up_arrow
'\xe0'
>>>down_arrow = msvcrt.getch()
>>>
>>>print down_arrow
'\xe0'
```

Answer (score 4):

This is explained in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html#msvcrt.getch):

> If the pressed key was a special function key, this will return '\000' or '\xe0'; the next call will return the keycode.

Under the covers, as you can see from [the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/PC/msvcrtmodule.c#L227), Python is just calling the MSVCRT function [`_getch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getch-getwch), which is sort of like the POSIX function [`getch`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/getch.html), but different in one key way:

> When reading a function key or an arrow key, each function must be called twice; the first call returns 0 or 0xE0, and the second call returns the actual key code.

The historical reason for this goes back to DOS compatibility in Windows NT 3.x (or, rather, Turbo C for DOS compatibility in Microsoft C++ for Windows NT).

IIRC (and I've probably got a few of the details wrong…), the basic idea was this: You'd make a BIOS call to get hi and lo values for the keyboard, meaning every key had a 16-bit value. Turbo C, to make things easier, provided a nice call that would map keys to their character in the current (8-bit) codepage, so `a` would give you back a single byte, `0x61`. But there wasn't enough room to map everything, so special keys like `VK_UP` would be returned unmapped, across two separate calls, first the hi byte `0xE0` and then the lo byte `0x50`. Microsoft copied that from Borland to make it easier to port code to their compiler, and then to port code from DOS/Win3.1 to NT, and so that's what MSVCRT still does today, and Python is just wrapping the function that does that.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2877857/908494) gives some more details.

Of course on most Unix terminals, the up arrow also send a sequence of characters, usually the same as the cursor-up display control sequence for that character, typically `ESC`, then `[`, then `A`. But people don't expect a single-character `getch`-like function to return a single value for every key on Unix, so nobody gets confused.