# How do I make my program do a specific thing after I press a certain key on my keyboard?

Tags: c, console, ascii

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    char ch;
    
    printf("Enter any character: \n");
    ch = fgetc(stdin);
    
    if(ch == 'A')
    {
        printf("A was inputed.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%c was inputed.\n", ch);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

So this is a simple program: When you input A and press enter, "A was inputed" gets printed. If you input any other character it will print " was inputed."

But I want to make it like this: When the right arrow key is *pressed*, it will print "Right Arrow Key", but when the left arrow key is *pressed*, it will print "Left Arrow Key".

How do I do this?

I can do this with the enter key by doing this.

```
if(ch == 0x0A)
{
printf("ENTER KEY was pressed\n");
}
else
{

}
```

I learned that 0x0A is the hexadecimal ASCII value of the enter key. So I thought I could do the same with other keys after I get their hexadecimal ASCII value. But I don't know the ones for the right arrow and left arrow keys.

EDIT: I should have mentioned that I use Windows 10.

Comment: The following link might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876275/what-are-the-ascii-values-of-up-down-left-right

Comment: There's also in issue of buffering. I don't think we can assume that fgetc() will return immediately after a single keystroke. I have sample code that will handle these issues, if this is Linux and a standard terminal emulator. If it is Linux, ncurses provides well-understood ways to handle both the keycode conversion and the buffering.

Comment: If you are on Windows, or targeting Windows I recommend using the WinApi https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/keyboard-input They allow you to detect all keys (as far as I know) which sounds like what you want.  On linux you would probably have to go through ASCII keys (or a function if one is available on given system)

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You have not specified OS...

This this answer will address the question from a *Windows* perspective.

Two items that can simplify your task in a Windows environment:

- The function [GetAsyncKeyState(int vKey)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate)
- A list of the [Virtual-Key Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes)

Which, along with every other keyboard definition, does include the arrow keys:

- `VK_LEFT  0x25 LEFT ARROW key`
- `VK_UP    0x26 UP ARROW key`
- `VK_RIGHT 0x27 RIGHT ARROW key`
- `VK_DOWN  0x28 DOWN ARROW key`

Together, these can be used to enable your code to capture single keystrokes as well as combinations of keystrokes, detect both *instantaneous* and *held* states all helping to determine the state of the keyboard.  Using these, your code example could be implemented like this:

```
void GetAppState(void)
{
    short state=0;
    short state1=0;
    
    state = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN);
    if (0x80000000 & state) //check instantaineous state of key
    {
       printf("ENTER KEY was pressed\n");
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    } 
    ...... and so on
```

To capture multiple simultaneous keystrokes, you can do something similar to this for example (capturing `<ctrl><shift><h>`)

```
state = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL);
    if (0x80000000 & state) //check instantaineous state of key
    {
        state = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT); 
        if (0x80000000 & state) //check instantaineous state of key
        {
            state = GetAsyncKeyState('h'); 
            state1 = GetAsyncKeyState('H'); 
            if ((0x80000000 & state) || 
                (0x80000000 & state1))
            {
```